# Why is the \d metacharacter not working in the find command with -regextype posix-egrep active?

Tags: find, regex, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have a list of .jpg files in my current directory with the following paths:

```
./ex.jpg
./ex1234.jpg
./ex4321.jpg
```

And **I am trying to match only those that contain numbers** with regular expressions and the `find` command. Here's the command I'm running:

```
find . -regextype posix-egrep -regex "\.\/ex\d+\.jpg"
```

However, this won't match anything in my directory. And even stranger is the fact that the following command (replacing `\d+` with `\d*`):

```
find . -regextype posix-egrep -regex "\.\/ex\d*\.jpg"
```

outputs *only* this:

```
./ex.jpg
```

I have tried this regular expression changing the `-regextype` command to all the other options available but this doesn't seem to make any impact.

Can someone explain this behavior?

My version of `find`: (GNU findutils) 4.7.0-git in Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS for Windows Subsystem for Linux.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\d` (for a decimal digit) is not supported by POSIX (or GNU grep) extended regular expression (ERE) syntax - as you can confirm easily:

```
$ echo 'foo1234bar' | grep -E '\d'
```

In fact `\d` comes from `perl`, and *is* supported by GNU grep in PCRE (perl-compatible regular expression) mode:

```
$ echo 'foo1234bar' | grep -P '\d'
foo1234bar
```

However that doesn't help much with `find` since AFAIK it doesn't yet provide a PCRE `regextype` - you will have to use the simple character range `[0-9]`, which is supported by both ERE and basic regular expressions (BRE):

```
find . -regextype posix-egrep -regex "\.\/ex[0-9]+\.jpg"
```

The reason `\d*\.jpg` matches `ex.jpg` is because `\d` is treated as literal `d` - and zero or more of anything matches everything.